# how to make backspace work in 'files'

Tags: pantheon-files, release-juno

juno,'Files' app, is it possible to go back to previous or upper level folder, by press 'backspace' key?
BR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alt left/right right is the keyboard shortcut for moving through history, just like in browsers.

Answer (score 1):

`<Alt>Up` is the keyboard shortcut you're looking for. As far as I know, `backspace` does nothing. If you want to change the keyboard shortcut, I think your only option is to change it in the source code and compile locally.